# Manually set a custom admin sub-menu selected?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

This question might have been asked already, and if so I apologize but none of the other answers pointed me in the right direction. I am developing my first Wordpress plugin. 
Lets say it contains the following admin pages:

- General Settings
- Add New Vendor
- Vendors
- Edit Vendor

Now, I do not want to display the *Edit Vendor* option in the menu, and I want to make it accessible using a link in *Vendors* page. My menu and *Vendors* page are:

[image]

Code to generate the menu:

```
function nes_general_settings_view () { 
    require_once("views/admin/general_settings.php");
}

function nes_vendor_view () { 
    require_once("views/admin/vendor.php");
}

function nes_vendor_new_view () {
    require_once("views/admin/vendor_new.php");
}

function nes_vendor_edit_view () {

    require_once("views/admin/vendor_edit.php");
}

add_action("admin_menu", function () {
    add_menu_page(
        "Service",  
        "Service",  
        "manage_options",            
        "nes_general_settings",      
        "nes_general_settings_view", 
        null,                        
        4                            
    );

    add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "General Settings", "General Settings", 0, "nes_general_settings", "nes_general_settings_view");

    add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "Vendors", "Vendors", 0, "nes_vendor", "nes_vendor_view");
    add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "New Vendor", "New Vendor", 0, "nes_vendor_new", "nes_vendor_new_view");
    add_submenu_page( "nes_fake_id", "Edit Vendor", "Edit Vendor", 0, "nes_vendor_edit", "nes_vendor_edit_view");

});
```

And Code to generate the link to *Edit Vendor* page:

```
<a href="<?=admin_url("admin.php?page=nes_vendor_edit")?>">Edit</a>
```

But when I am in *Edit Vendor* page, my menu is not selected.

[image]

**Now my question is:** How do I set  the *Service > Vendors* submenu to the currently selected Admin menu, when I am on the *Edit Vendor* Page? Please give me an example, since I am really new to WordPress.

Comment: Try adding a Page Hook Suffix, and make sure your menu matches the [WordPress Codex on Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)

Comment: I asked the same question on stackoverflow and got the answer as adding proper classes to the menu and the submenu using jQuery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468919/how-to-manually-set-a-custom-admin-submenu-selected